# test POST mocha - chai : return 500

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

actually right now im writing API to create, get, update, and delete data using node js. my code working in a good shape.

i try it using postman to post data, it adding new data to my db.

then i want to use testing unit, named mocha - chai.

this my code :

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let server = require('server');
let expect = require("chai").expect;
let should = require("should");

let request = require("superagent");
let util = require("util");

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('API Clinic Test', function() {

  it('should add a SINGLE clinic on /api/v1/clinic POST', function(done) {
  chai.request('http://localhost:5000')
      .post('/api/v1/clinic')
      .send({'clinic_name': 'Clinic Dummy', 'address': 'Bandung', 'phone':'888 888', 'fax':'888 888'})
      .end(function(err, res){
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        done();
      }); 
  });
```

});

if success it should return code 200.
but when i run mocha, i got this error.

[image]

i dont understad. i try using postman, it can added new data.
but why i got return 500 code when i using mocha?
is there something wrong in my codes?

please help me.

thank you.

Comment: Inspect the response object and server logs, try debugging server code, etc. The only thing clear from your question is that you are indeed receiving an error response, so, I believe, you need to follow up on the error you are getting, not the test setup

Comment: how to do that? i browsing here and there, but get nothing. pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Make your function asynchronous, testing function pretends to be executed both at the same time due to that some fail.

```js
it('should add a SINGLE clinic on /api/v1/clinic POST', async function(done) {
  await chai.request('http://localhost:5000')
    .post('/api/v1/clinic')
    .send({'clinic_name': 'Clinic Dummy', 'address': 'Bandung', 'phone':'888 888', 'fax':'888 888'})
    .end(function(err, res) {
      expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
      done();
    });
```